# What is the maximum spy level in CivV

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

What is the maximum spy level in CivV Gods & Kings?

Maximum level my spies have reached was "special agent", never managed to get them above this grade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three spy ranks: Recruit, Agent, and Special Agent.

So Special Agent is the highest attainable rank.